# Add each column to a new data frame

Tags: r, dataset

For example, I have a data frame with 4 columns:
`col1 col2 col3 col4`

I would like to get a new data frame by accumulating each column:
`col1 col1+col2 col1+col2+col3 col1+col2+col3+col4`

How should I write in R?

Comment: This is a programming question not a statistics question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R, you can calculate row-wise `cumsum` using `apply`.

Using @Henry's data :

```
startdf[] <- t(apply(startdf, 1, cumsum))
startdf

#  col1 col2 col3 col4
#1    1   21  321 4321
#2    4   34  234 1234
```

Answer (score 2):

If this was a matrix then you could use `rowCumsums` from the `matrixStats` package

so starting with a dataframe and returning to a dataframe I suppose you could try something like

```
library(matrixStats)
startdf <- data.frame(col1=c(1,4), col2=c(20,30), 
                 col3=c(300,200), col4=c(4000,1000))
finishdf <- as.data.frame(rowCumsums(as.matrix(startdf)))
```

to go from

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    1   20  300 4000
2    4   30  200 1000
```

to

```
  V1 V2  V3   V4
1  1 21 321 4321
2  4 34 234 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R (not as efficient or clean as Ronak's) [using Henry's data]:

```
data.frame(Reduce(rbind, Map(cumsum, data.frame(t(startdf)))), row.names = NULL)
```